# Using pandas groupby().apply(list) on multiple columns at once

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to combine multiple rows of a dataframe into one row, with the columns with different values being combined in a list. There are multiple columns with different values.

The `df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(list)` works well if only 1 column ('b' in this instance) has to be made to a list, but I can't figure out how to do it for multiple columns.

Dataframe:

```
   a  b  c       d
0  1  b  1   first
1  1  b  2  second
2  2  c  1   third
3  2  c  2  fourth
4  2  c  3   fifth
```

Prefered dataframe post operation:

```
   a  b          c                       d
0  1  b     [1, 2]         [first, second]
1  2  c  [1, 2, 3]  [third, fourth, fifth]
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: `df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c', 'd'].agg(list)`

Comment: @Georgy: you don't even need to specify `column`. It is `df.groupby(['a', 'b']).agg(list)`

Answer (score 13):

```
df = df.groupby(['a','b']).apply(lambda x: [list(x['c']), list(x['d'])]).apply(pd.Series)
df.columns =['a','b','c','d']
```

**Output**

```
   a  b          c                       d
0  1  b     [1, 2]         [first, second]
1  2  c  [1, 2, 3]  [third, fourth, fifth]
```

Comment: This solution worked for me.